# Performance of using setInterval in Vue's mounted method?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, intervals

I'm using the following code to show a datetime (using momentjs) that updates every second. I've read discussion about the performance issue's that may or may not be caused by setInterval and setTimeout.

**Is this the most efficient way of going about this? What is thé common way to use intervals in single page applications?**

```
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return {
      dateTime: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateTimer () {
      this.dateTime = moment().format()
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.updateTimer, 1000)
  }
}
```

The discussion can be found here:
https://forum.vuejs.org/t/basic-problem-making-a-clock-update-in-vue/642/14 (it is 3 years old now)

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

Comment: @Taplar Watchers are used to monitor data in Vue instances that changes, it doesn't have built-in counters or intervals, why are you referring to the watcher?

Comment: An interval could be used to update a data property, which could be watched to update the page.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, What's the performance advantage over just having a setInterval in my mounted or created method?

Comment: Side stepping the discussion on performance, which is off topic, are you actually having performance issues?  Your question is phrased more as a discussion, rather than asking for a solution to a specific problem.

Comment: Calling `setInterval` in `mounted` seems fine to me. Make sure you call `clearInterval` when the component is destroyed. There is no performance problem with using `setInterval`. The discussion in that forum thread is about a bug in their code, not a problem with using `setInterval`.